# Change width of an div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to change the width of an div with jquery:

```
<div class="blue-slider">
<p>jajjja</p>
</div>
```

But my jquery somehow wont work! (I feel ashamed)

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(".blue-slider").width( 30 );
});
```

Here`s the same code on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khFYW/2/

Comment: Weird fiddle...all the stuff was in the wrong boxes! Bear in mind a lot of the time with the jQuery methods that it wants you to pass in the unit as well (usually px)

Comment: Your Fiddle is not the same code; it's a Javascript syntax error.

Comment: @Katstevens: No; jQuery always defaults to `px`.

Comment: did you even read the jQuery docs ?

Comment: Sorry guys, before i created this question, i tried several things myself, that normally would have worked. So now i recociced that i always referd to "slider" but the class name was "slide"!

Answer (score 6):

You had multiple problems in the fiddle

1. You had HTML where CSS should be and vice-versa
2. Your fiddle setting was such that the JS was already being executed onload. Still you had an extra `load()` binding inside

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khFYW/4/

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".blue-slider").width( '30px' );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the CSS method of jQuery.

`$(".blue-slider").css( "width","600px" );`

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/khFYW/3/

Comment: Is there a need? I think $('.blue-slider').width('600px'); should work

Comment: It should work but width() doesn't require units, just an integer value, so the original should work. It can be either 600 or "600px".

Comment: `width()` will work just as fine. Usage of `width()` isn't the reason for the error in this case.

Comment: The true error is in the original fiddle you placed the CSS code and HTML code in the wrong places, and you had to onLoad functions

Answer (score 1):

### Em Sta Please RTM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".blue-slider").css('width','600px').css('background-color','red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khFYW/6/

Comment: How can i first save the window width in a var and then insert it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".blue-slider").css('width', '600px');
});
```

Using the css jQuery function, I got the result that I believe you are looking for. Though my values are different, you can just substitute your own to get the exact styling you're looking for.

In order to create more than one css using jQuery change you can do the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/KY3jJ/

```
$(".blue-slider").css({
  "width" : "600px",
  "height" : "200px",
  "background-color" : "#09c"
});
```

Please note the use of "}" (brackets) in your function when trying to change multiple properties at once.